# Not able to get facebook friend list using facebook-graph-api version2.0

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch logged in user's friend list. I am using this

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error){
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends){
        NSLog(@"%@", friend);
    }
}];
```

and what i need to pass in parameters and HTTPMethod?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent Facebook update that now after 30 April you need to submit Facebook App in Review for getting permission for user_friend.

[See Upgrading from 3.13 to 3.14](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading)

- Developers asking for more than `public_profile`, `email`, and `user_friends` will need to submit their apps for review by Facebook to approve the permissions the app will request. See the [Permissions Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) for details. Existing apps have one year before they are required to go through review, including updates to existing apps. Apps created after April 30th, 2014 must go through review.
- When requesting permissions (including at time of login), people can now decline individual permissions requested.
  Several new methods have been added to help with this new flow:

please check [Developer Facebook Review Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

Comment: to get user_friends is it necessary to review the app...?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Facebook Friend List
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];

[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary* result,NSError *error)
 {
     NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
     //NSLog(@"%@",friends);

     [app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd removeAllObjects];

     // CREATE ARRAY OF ALL FRIEND LIST OF FACEBOOK

     for (int i=0; i < [friends count]; i++)
     {
         // ADD IMAGE URL IN ARRAY
         NSString *s1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"first_name"]];
         NSString *s2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];
         NSString *s3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"last_name"]];
         NSString *s4=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
         NSString *s5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"username"]];
         NSString *s6=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?", [[friends objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];

         NSMutableDictionary *dictFriend=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [dictFriend setObject:s1 forKey:@"first_name"];
         [dictFriend setObject:s2 forKey:@"id"];
         [dictFriend setObject:s3 forKey:@"last_name"];
         [dictFriend setObject:s4 forKey:@"name"];
         [dictFriend setObject:s5 forKey:@"username"];
         [dictFriend setObject:s6 forKey:@"ImgUrl"];

         [app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd addObject:dictFriend];
         [app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd retain];
     }
     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
     sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
     NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
     [app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
     [sortDescriptor release];
 }];
```

Comment: not working anymore.if you are using old one then there is error on other Feature.

Comment: [FBRequest requestForMyFriends] is not available. Instead [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:nil]; is to be used. Though thanks for your efforts.

Comment: as i said that is not longer available into facebook sdk now a days. you must submit you facebook app as a review from dev.facebook